# How to hide an ancestor element and the element after the ancestor on click?

Tags: jquery, html

On click to `span.btn`, I'd like to hide the `li.item` ancestor and the next `li.item`. How do I do that for the HTML below?

```
<ul id="list">
   <li class="item"><div><span class="btn">remove</span></div></li>
   <li class="item">text</li>
   <li class="item">text</li>
   <li class="item"><div><span class="btn">remove</span></div></li>
   <li class="item">text</li>
   <li class="item">text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){

   var $this = $(this);
   var $parentLi = $this.parents('li');
   var $nextLi = $parentLi.next('li');

   $parentLi.hide();
   $nextLi.hide();
})
```